# Using Dynamic Memory get every second element in a char array into another

Tags: c

I've been tasked with getting writing a function that uses dynamic memory and will take a string `s` and pull out every second element of the string, and then return a new string with those elements. So far my code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char* skipping(const char* s)
{
    int inc = 0; //new list incrementer
    int len = strlen(s);
    char* new_s = malloc(len + 1); 
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i+=2) {
        new_s[inc] = s[i];
        inc++;
    }
    return new_s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* s = skipping("0123456789");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This works, however when I run it using Valgrind I get told I have an error, which comes from using `strlen`, but I can't seem to fix it. Any help would be awesome!

Error messages: (in valgrind)

```
==4596== 
==4596== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

==4596==    at 0x4C32D08: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==4596==    by 0x4EBC9D1: puts (ioputs.c:35)

==4596==    by 0x1087B4: main (in /home/ryan/ENCE260/lab6)

==4596== 

02468             //this is the expected output

==4596== 

==4596== HEAP SUMMARY:

==4596==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==4596==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,035 bytes allocated

==4596== 

==4596== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

==4596== 

==4596== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This includes copies of your entire program and the actual error messages you've got. My crystall ball says the error is in not null-terminating new_s. And why `i < len - 1`?

Comment: valgrind will show an error if you don't free the memory that you 'malloc'ed.

Comment: Probably not the error, but I'm not sure why you used `len - 1` instead of `len` in the loop condition. Also, you haven't NUL-terminated `new_s` after copying

Comment: Just added in the other bits of info, sorry this is my first time posting :)

Comment: Oh, the error is about `strlen` in library code, not your code – when you do `printf("%s\n", s);`. (Compiling with `-Og -g` flags before running valgrind should get you line numbers to help with that.) As people have mentioned, the problem is that `new_s` isn’t terminated.

Comment: Try NUL-terminating `new_s` (`new_s[inc] = '\0'`) after the loop and see if the error still persists.

Comment: @CoolGuy that was it thank you. seems trivial now haha

Comment: 1) `return new_s;` ==> `new_s[inc] = '\0'; return new_s;` 2) `i < len - 1;` ==> `i < len;` 3) `malloc(len + 1);` ==> `malloc((len + 3)/2);`

Comment: @4386427 - the `malloc((len + 3)/2);` is clever for the specific loop incrementing `i+=2`, but may be confusing to those learning dynamical allocation, and may be overlooked when changing the loop conditions. Good rule of thumb for character strings is always `len + 1`. I'd rather over-allocate by `10K` than under-allocate by `1 :)` (if you are on an embedded system with memory critically short, sure, but otherwise for a 5-character gamble, it may add more complication than it saves memory)

Answer (score 1):

Why is Valgrind reporting this error?

From the Valgrind [online manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals) on the [use of uninitialised or unaddressable values in system calls](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.bad-syscall-args):

> Sources of **uninitialised data** tend to be:
>   - Local variables in procedures which have not been initialised.
>   - **The contents of heap blocks (allocated with malloc, new, or a similar function)**        before you (or a constructor) write something there.

Valgrind will complain if:

> the program has **written uninitialised junk from the heap block to the standard output**.

Since you have used `s` in `printf` without null-terminating it, it caused the error.